# ORA-01802: Julian date is out of range although select statement does not include date manipulation

Tags: sql, oracle, julian-date

I got `ORA-01802: Julian date is out of range` when executing the select statement below, which have nothing to do with dates

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dual
WHERE
    (
        (
            ( ltrim(TO_CHAR(109,'0000') )
              || ltrim(TO_CHAR(2020,'0000') )
              || ltrim(TO_CHAR(6,'000') )
              || ltrim(TO_CHAR(601,'000') )
              || ltrim(TO_CHAR(0,'000') )
              || ltrim(TO_CHAR(805406,'000000') )
              || ltrim(TO_CHAR(729,'000') )
              || ltrim(TO_CHAR(400,'0000') )
              || ltrim(TO_CHAR(400,'0000') )
              || ltrim(TO_CHAR(938,'000') )
              || ( 0 )
              || ( '####################' ) ) = ltrim('01092020005501000505114729000000000000####################')
            AND ( 0 = 0 )
        )
        OR ( ltrim(TO_CHAR(109,'0000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(2020,'0000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(6,'000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(601,'000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(0,'000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(805406,'000000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(729,'000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(400,'0000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(400,'0000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(938,'000') )
             || ( 0 )
             || ( '####################' ) ) = (
            SELECT
                MAX(ltrim(TO_CHAR(109,'0000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(2020,'0000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(6,'000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(601,'000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(0,'000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(805406,'000000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(729,'000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(400,'0000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(400,'0000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(938,'000') )
                      || (0)
                      || ('####################') )
            FROM
                dual
            WHERE
                ( ltrim(TO_CHAR(109,'0000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(2020,'0000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(6,'000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(601,'000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(0,'000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(805406,'000000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(729,'000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(400,'0000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(400,'0000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(938,'000') )
                  || ( 0 )
                  || ( '####################' ) ) < ltrim('01092020005501000505114729000000000000####################')
                AND ( 0 = 1 )
        )
        OR ( ltrim(TO_CHAR(109,'0000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(2020,'0000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(6,'000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(601,'000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(0,'000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(805406,'000000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(729,'000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(400,'0000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(400,'0000') )
             || ltrim(TO_CHAR(938,'000') )
             || ( 0 )
             || ( '####################' ) ) = (
            SELECT
                MIN(ltrim(TO_CHAR(109,'0000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(2020,'0000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(6,'000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(601,'000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(0,'000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(805406,'000000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(729,'000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(400,'0000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(400,'0000') )
                      || ltrim(TO_CHAR(938,'000') )
                      || (0)
                      || ('####################') )
            FROM
                dual
            WHERE
                ( ltrim(TO_CHAR(109,'0000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(2020,'0000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(6,'000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(601,'000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(0,'000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(805406,'000000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(729,'000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(400,'0000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(400,'0000') )
                  || ltrim(TO_CHAR(938,'000') )
                  || ( 0 )
                  || ( '####################' ) ) > ltrim('01092020005501000505114729000000000000####################')
                AND ( 0 = 2 )
        )
    );
```

I'm using `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`

Comment: weird things + enormous SQL statement = remove bits from your SQL until you find the culprit

Comment: Works for me on the same database version. Though, in order to get *something*, I set those `and 0 = 1` conditions to be *true*, but - finally - I got `x` as a result. Are you sure that this is the query that returned that error? There's really nothing that suggests that Julian date is involved (no `TO_CHAR` with `'J'`).

Comment: Works fine for me on Oracle 11.2 and 18.

Comment: Any chance NLS settings could influence this?

Comment: @Littlefoot I also tried this on another db with the same version and worked, but in this particular environment it's not working.

Comment: This sounds rather like bug 27442505; except you aren't using FM. (Though you maybe should be; `ltrim(TO_CHAR(938,'000'))` could be simplified to `TO_CHAR(938,'FM000')` etc.) Is `cursor_sharing` set differently in the two DBs you tried this in? As it doesn't quite match, might be worth raising a service request with Oracle.

Comment: Works fine for me in Oracle 19c